# Trying to access file inside ibm cloud object storage Bucket and getting CORS error

Tags: html, cors

I'm trying to access a file inside of a bucket on ibmcloud Object Storage I created and I'm receiving "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error. How can I solve that? Is there any way i can add CORS policy on my bucket?

I'm trying to access the file directly from frontend using Jquery Ajax. So i really needed a way to give permission on the bucket!

Comment: Is it possible to provide more details of how you re accessing the file e.g. the code you are using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it adding a CORS configuration file on the bucket, sending the following command:

ibmcloud cos put-bucket-cors --bucket BUCKETNAME--cors-configuration file://FILE_PATH  --region REGION

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you should first search the official documentation https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage-cli-plugin?topic=cloud-object-storage-cli-ic-cos-cli#ic-set-bucket-cors

Answer (score 0):

**This is how I was able to fix CORS error on Cloud storage.**
**cors-config.txt was uploaded to IBM Cloud shell.**

ibmcloud cos bucket-cors-put --bucket  --region  --cors-configuration file://cors-config.txt

```
OK
Successfully set CORS configuration on bucket: <bucketname>
```

ibmcloud cos bucket-cors-get --bucket  --region  --output text

```
OK
The CORS configuration of <bucketname>:
{
  CORSRules: [{
      AllowedMethods: ["GET"],
      AllowedOrigins: ["*"],
      MaxAgeSeconds: 3000
   }]
}
```